# Difficulty to write a collection mathematicaly

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am finding it difficult to write a collection "with in" the set symbol

Let $X,Y$ be two topological spaces and $f:X\times Y\to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $D\subseteq X\times Y$. Let $A=\{(x,y)\in D:~(x,y)$ satisfies property $p\}$. Now, I want to consider the collection

$B:=$ all those points $x\in \pi_1(A)$ such that there exists $y\in \pi_2(A)$ with $(x,y)$ satisfies the property $p$ and $f(x,y)\geq 0$.

How, I will define this set in complete notation (without using any language) under the set symbol. Also, I will not prefer to use the symbol $\ni$ (i.e., such that).

Comment: If you want to be kind to your readers, use words rather than set notation free of language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want
$$B := \pi_1\bigl(f^{-1}\bigl([0,\infty)\bigr)\cap A\bigr).$$

Comment: oh wow! Thank you so much @Hagenvoneitzen

Comment: This definition of $B$ works provided there is no $(x,y) \in \pi_1(A) \times \pi_2(A)$ that satisfies property $p$ and s.t. $f(x,y) \ge 0$ but $(x,y) \notin D$. Perhaps it's an oversight, but OP's description of $B$ doesn't require that $(x,y) \in D$